# Detecting finalize exceptions within a unit test

Tags: .net, testing, memory-leaks, finalize

Is there a way to force all objects created during a unit test to finalise? The issue I keep running into is that any leaks due to lost `GCHandle` instances only seem to be finalised when the process itself (not the `AppDomain`!) terminates, which is after all the tests in the assembly have run (and potentially "passed").

My best, but insufficient, attempt in C#:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    ~Foo() { Dispose(); }
    public void Dispose() { throw new Exception(); }
}

[TestClass]
public class Finalise
{
    void bar()
    {
        GCHandle.Alloc(new Foo()); // leak
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DetectFinalizeException()
    {
        bar();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

Running this will result in a "passed" test, but with a notification that a background thread had an unhandled exception. In an assembly with multiple tests, this is less than ideal.

Comment: It's really rare to need a finalizer. Are you sure that you need one?

Comment: It's a C++/CLI class that loads up a native class. The finaliser is so the C++/CLI class can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you actually want to test the Dispose method. If that's the case, why not just call the Dipose method directly?

The GC will run on the thread that calls it. So another alternative would be to call the GC.Collection method within your test.

EDIT: Have you tried calling [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) in your unit test? I've never needed to do exactly what you are trying to do, but from what I understand the the garabage collector should run within your unit test's thread, thus allowing your unit test to catch any exceptions.

Comment: Not quite. I want to test that there were no problems in the finalisers in any of the objects created during a given test run. In situations more complex than my little sample above, is it possibly to ensure that no objects created during the function will crash when they finalise?